# Rails many to many (has_many :through) - how can a form add the children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a many-to-many relationship between Users table and Accounts table, implemented with the `:has_many, :through` method. Users can have multiple accounts and accounts can have multiple users.

I have a form where the user selects all the accounts he wants to be associated with. I want to associate the accounts to the User object so that I can query `@user.accounts` and have an updated list.

```
class User
   has_many :accountings
   has_many :accounts, :through => :accountings

class Neighborhood   
   has_many :accountings   
   has_many :users, :through => :accountings

class Accountings
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :accountings
```

How should I implement the form that sends the account IDs and updates the db?

I feel like this may be a basic question but am looking for the Rails way to do things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How should I implement this form?

Comment: Try watching this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised

Comment: Thanks Austin, that was the right video to watch. I'll post an answer soon to help those who come across this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the following for checkboxes (angular):

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="user[account_ids][]"
    value="{{ hood.id }}">{{ hood.name }} </div>
```

This will update the model's many-to-many relationship so that I can query user.account_ids and get an updated list.